# RPi Pyaudio/Portaudio + ALSA: How to select/change mux inputs

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, alsa, pyaudio, portaudio

I'm working on a project that is using a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian and an SGTL5000 based sound card (FePi.)  I have no problem selecting the card and getting samples in both directions - once I have configured the multiplexer to properly select line In/Out.  I did this with Alsamixer. I want to automate the process so that the only step required is to run the application.

I don't see a way to do this using PyAudio/PortAudio.  Is my only option the ALSA API or is there a way to do this with PyAudio (or PortAudio) that I'm not spotting?

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide.

Oz (in DFW)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, I wanted to automate changing mux settings but I wanted to adjust inputs not exposed by alsamixer too.

To deal with the limitations of the driver I ended up porting over the Teensy 3.x sgtl5000 control software to the pi yesterday

https://github.com/Swap-File/pi-sgtl5000

You could force feed the same commands via i2c via python.

The only downside is, once you start force feeding the sound card i2c commands, you break alsamixer (and anything else that might try to adjust it's own volume settings).